# No Results found in the Search Results

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display "No Results Found" in the case where someone uses my search feature to search for something that returns no results.

Currently it does not display any text if no results found.

See codepen for my code. I have also attached the code in the question.

https://codepen.io/magic12/pen/ZExKNjY

```js
    function myFunction() {
      const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
      const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
      for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
        const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
        tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
      }
    }
```

```css
    table.table_brdr td {
        padding: 8px 10px;
        border: none;
    }
    
    table.table_brdr th {
        background-color: #a6a6a6;
        color: black;
    }
    
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
          background-color#D3D3D3;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 20%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
```

```html
    <p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search" title="Searche"></p>
    <table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th><strong>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>test12</td>
    <td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>abctd <td>
    <td>09/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>abctd </td>
    <td>06/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
    
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: It is just filtering based on the search criteria. In order to show a row which is not currently on the page, you would need to create it somewhere, and then show it once a condition that you monitor is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the solution in the snippet might work.

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById("myInput")
const inputMessage = document.getElementById("input-message")
searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction)

function myFunction(e) {
  const userInput = (e.target.value || '').toUpperCase()
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  let count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    const rowDisplay = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
    tableRows[i].style.display = rowDisplay
    count += rowDisplay ? 0 : 1
  }
  setInputMessage(userInput === "" ? "" : count)
}

function setInputMessage(n) {
  let message = "&nbsp;"
  if (typeof n === "number") {
    if (!n) {
      message = "No results found."
    } else {
      message = `${n} result${n === 1 ? "" : "s"} found`
    }
  }
  inputMessage.innerHTML = message
}
```

```css
table.table_brdr td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color#D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.mb-3 {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-3">
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search" title="Searche">
  <div id="input-message">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th><strong>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test12</td>
      <td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
      <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>New Column</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>abctd</td>
      <td>09/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th> New Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>abctd </td>
      <td>06/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simply way is create an empty div for the message, and just have a counter adding up matching results. Then have an if statement if that variable is 0. There are other ways that use less code but harder to understand array functions, this is clean and simple. Also, you can move the table and new errors variables outside of the function.

```js
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  let errors = document.querySelector(".errors");

function myFunction() {
  const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();


  errors.innerHTML = "";
  let found = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    if(rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput)){
      found ++;
      tableRows[i].style.display ="block";
    }
    else{
       tableRows[i].style.display ="none";
    }
  }
  
  if(found == 0){
    errors.innerHTML = "NO RESULTS FOUND";
  }
  
}
```

```css
table.table_brdr td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color#D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search" title="Searche"></p>

<div class="errors"></div>

<table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th><strong>Column2</strong></th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>test12</td>
    <td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
    <td>03/30/2017</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>abctd <td>
    <td>09/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
      
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th> New Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>abctd </td>
    <td>06/30/2019</td>
    </tr>
    
    </tbody></table>
```